# Valgrind error : Invalid read/write in pthread_cancel in condition wait

Tags: c, pthreads, valgrind

Valgrind is reporting an invalid read/write in pthread_cond_wait() if the thread is cancelled while waiting in the condition.
Not sure, why is that happening or if this is a known issue :

```
==321== Invalid write of size 4
==321==    at 0x4DF5785: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/i386-linux-
gnu/libgcc_s.so.1)
==321==    by 0x4059E1A: pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 
(pthread_cond_timedwait.S:245)
==321==    by 0x49DE28F: ???
==321==  Address 0x49de210 is on thread 2's stack
==321== 
==321== Invalid read of size 4
==321==    at 0x4DF579D: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/i386-linux-
gnu/libgcc_s.so.1)
==321==  Address 0x49de210 is on thread 2's stack
```

The minimal runnable code is as under :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_cond_t notification_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t notification_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
time_t interval = 0;
pthread_t thread;
struct timespec ts;

void cleanup_handler(void *plock)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(plock);
}

void *wait_on_condition(void *arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, &notification_mutex);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    interval = time(NULL) + 5; //(If we replace 5 with 0, code just runs fine)
    ts.tv_nsec = 0;
    ts.tv_sec = interval;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&notification_mutex);
    pthread_cond_timedwait(&notification_cond, &notification_mutex, &ts);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&notification_mutex);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, wait_on_condition, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(thread);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to return something from `wait_on_condition`. For example `int ret = 0; pthread_exit(&ret);`.

Comment: I'm not experience with thread cancellation, but it sure looks like you're doing things right. However, I wouldn't bet whether this is a problem in the library or whether it's one of those instances where the library is doing something that's technically undefined/unspecified behavior but since it's "the implementation" it can technically do things that are undefined or unspecified that a mere user isn't allowed to count on.  If it's the latter, Valgrind may need to be configured or fixed to ignore that particular 'false positive'.

Comment: I do not get any warning from Valgrind running your code. Which compiler and Valgrind version do you use? How do you run Valgrind?

Comment: compiler  :  gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2,  valgrind : valgrind-3.10.0,  Command : valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-leak-kinds=all  <executable>

Comment: Is this before or after adding a `pthread_exit(NULL)` in your function `wait_on_condition`?

Comment: After adding the `pthread_exit(NULL)` and a cast to `pthread_mutex_t` in the `cleanup_handler`, I get no errors with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) and valgrind 3.10.0. I suspect that you have a mismatch between valgrind and gcc versions. Update gcc to 4.9.2 or update both gcc and valgrind to newer versions

Comment: Adding a cast or pthread_exit is not solving the issue for me. And I don't see why would it make any difference as the thread is exiting in condition wait and will never reach the end of function to execute pthread_exit. Were you getting the same problems reported from valgrind before adding these checks in your version of gcc ?